# How to save to vector coordinates of white pixels?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to loop through a binarized `cv::Mat` and save all coordinates of pixels with a value of `255`.

```
cv::Mat bin;                                                    
std::vector<cv::Point2i> binVec;
int h = 0;
int white = 254;    //Just for comparison with pointer of Matrix value
for (int i = 0; i < bin.rows; i++, h++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < bin.cols; j++, h++) {
        int* p = bin.ptr<int>(h);   //Pointer to bin Data, should loop through Matrix
        if (p >= &white)            //If a white pixel has been found, push i and j in binVec
            binVec.push_back(cv::Point2i(i, j));
    }
}
```

This snippet is not working, and I don't know why.

> Exception thrown at 0x76C6C42D in example.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0019E4F4.
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x76C6C42D in example.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0019E4F4.

So how can I count `h` and let the pointer work?

Comment: Have you used a debugger?

Comment: you dont initialize `h`

Comment: oh yea, when i compressed my code i forgot to take the initialization, I'll edit the code.

Comment: int* p = bin.ptr<int>(h) will get a pointer to row h but you increment h for each pixel, not only for each row. please try val = mat.at<type>(i,j) instead! Where type depends on your image type and is probably uchar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can avoid to scan the image. To save the coordinates of all white pixels in a vector you can do like:

```
Mat bin;
// fill bin with some value

std::vector<Point> binVec;
findNonZero(bin == 255, binVec);
```

---

You can use `Point` instead of `Point2i`, since they are the same:

```
typedef Point2i Point;
```

---

If you really want to use a for loop, you should do like:

```
const uchar white = 255;
for (int r = 0; r < bin.rows; ++r) 
{
    uchar* ptr = bin.ptr<uchar>(r);
    for(int c = 0; c < bin.cols; ++c) 
    {
        if (ptr[c] == 255) {
            binVec.push_back(Point(c,r));
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that:

- you binary image is probably  `CV_8UC1`, and not a `CV_32SC1`, so you should use `uchar` instead of `int`.
- `bin.ptr<...>(i)` gives you a pointer to the start of the i-th row, so you should take it out of the inner loop.
- you should compare the *values*, not the *address*.
- `Point` take as parameters `x` (*cols*) and `y` (*rows*), while you are passing `i` (*rows*) and `j` (*cols*). So you need to swap them.
- this loop can be further optimized, but for your task I strongly recommend the `findNonZero` approach, so I don't show it here.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

1. You should only increment `h` in the inner loop
2. You should compare the value pointed at by `p` with `h`, not compare `p` with the address of `h`.

So

```
cv::Mat bin;                                                    
std::vector<cv::Point2i> binVec;

int h = 0;
int white = 254;    //Just for comparison with pointer of Matrix value
for (int i = 0; i < bin.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < bin.cols; j++) {
        int* p = bin.ptr<int>(h++);   //Pointer to bin Data, should loop through Matrix
        if (*p >= white)            //If a white pixel has been found, push i and j in binVec
            binVec.push_back(cv::Point2i(i, j));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i will take Miki's answer

Comment: That'll be because: 1.  I've got the definition of bin.ptr wrong.  2.  I didn't point out the CV_8UC1 trap.  3.  I didn't point out the built in function to do the hard work.  tl;dr - His is a *much* better answer.